# (node:13848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.member.roles.some is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

im trying to make a kicka command but it won't work because of this error i get "(node:13848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.member.roles.some is not a function"

My code `client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if(command === "kick") {
    if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Administrator", "Moderator"].includes(r.name)) )
      return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!");
    let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
    if(!member)
      return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server");
    if(!member.kickable) 
      return message.reply("I cannot kick this user! Do they have a higher role? Do I have kick permissions?");
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    if(!reason) reason = "No reason provided";

    await member.kick(reason)
      .catch(error => message.reply(`Sorry ${message.author} I couldn't kick because of : ${error}`));
    message.reply(`${member.user.tag} has been kicked by ${message.author.tag} because: ${reason}`);

  }});`
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that I get the error when trying to do the kick command!

Comment: If `message.member.roles.some` is not a function, it means that `message.member.roles` is not an Array. Check what it is, by doing `console.log`, for example

Answer (score 2):

If your discord.js version is 12.0.0 or over, it is [`message.member.roles.cache.some()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache). This also includes other changes such as `message.guild.members.get(args[0])` is now [`message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=cache). This is because of the newly added managers. You can read more about v12 changes [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html). If you are not on v12, [`message.member.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.1.0/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles) in your code was most likely overwritten and no longer is a Collection.